# Reflection, emission and absorption of light

Tags: visible-light, reflection, absorption

When you shine a light on an object, some of it gets reflected and the rest gets absorbed.
$A + r = 1$ Where r is the amount of light reflected per sec in $1m^2$ and A is the amount of light absorbed per sec in $1m^2$.

However, when the object emits light when the light reaches the surface some of it gets emitted but the rest gets reflected back. Do we get the same ratio as shining light from outside the object or?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: Assume 10 joules of light hit the surface 6 joules get reflected and 4 joules get absorbed. Now assume the object emits 10 j of energy when it reach the boundary will we have the same ratio? As in 6 joules get reflected back into the object and 4 joules get emitted

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. If the total energy is 10 then whatever combination of absorption, reflection and transmission you have, it will still equal 10.

Comment: I meant will the boundary still reflect 6 joules even if it came from inside the object, As there is no difference between which side the light comes.